# Custom animation for changing height of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewanimation

I want to make animation of changing UITableViewCell height with UIView animation (in future with spring animation).

So I have:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    UILabel *viewLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 40.0f)];
    viewLabel.text = @"Test";
    viewLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:viewLabel];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [self animateCell:indexPath andTableView:tableView];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}


- (void)animateCell:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath andTableView:(UITableView*)tableView
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations: ^
     {
         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
         CGRect rect = cell.frame;
         rect.size.height = 90.0f;
         cell.frame = rect;
         NSLog(@"%f", cell.frame.size.height);
     }];
}
```

But it does not work. But if I`m adding:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([indexPath isEqual:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]])
    {
        return 90.0f;
    }
    return 40.0f;
}
```

I see that cell is changing its height and animation is applied to custom cell that is created in animateCell method

Comment: When you call endUpdates, UITableView performs default animation. Animation properties are based on table view's datasource values.

Comment: So I do not need to call beginUpdates and endUpdates and make handling for custom animation (change position of near cells to animated one)?

Comment: What your animation should be?

Comment: Changing height of selected cell with bounce effect (new UIView animation with spring effect)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should not use `beginUpdate`/`endUpdates` methods and perform animations manually before calling `reloadData`. The final state of cells (after animation) are defined with datasource. Here's an example of animation in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _selectedIndexPath = indexPath;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        // move down cells which are below selected one
        for (UITableViewCell *cell in tableView.visibleCells) {
            NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

            if (cellIndexPath.row > indexPath.row) {
                CGRect frame = cell.frame;
                frame.origin.y += kTargetHeight - tableView.rowHeight;
                cell.frame = frame;
            }
        }
        // expand selected cell
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        CGRect frame = cell.frame;
        frame.size.height = kTargetHeight;
        cell.frame = frame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [tableView reloadData];  // commit final state
    }];
}
```

The final state of selected cell:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([indexPath isEqual:_selectedIndexPath]) {
        return kTargetHeight;
    }

    return tableView.rowHeight;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but there is a blink due [tableView reloadData]

Comment: Thanks, it works, but there is a blink due [tableView reloadData]This gives better look : [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView endUpdates];

Comment: You know, did similar for didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: and does not work

Comment: There is also an issue when making a cell smaller. If there are more cells than fit in the list, the last (virtual) cells will not be accessible via tableView.visibleCells. As the cell becomes smaller, you will see a gap at the bottom until the animation is done and the virtual cells at the bottom are added.